# Python Flask WSGI file is ignoring user's environment variables

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, wsgi

I have configured Apache on Ubuntu 12.04 to run my Python Flask web application using WSGI. Here is part of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    WSGIDaemonProcess 3dkit user=3dkit group=3dkit threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /3dkit /3dkit/kit.wsgi
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Location /3dkit>
    WSGIProcessGroup 3dkit
    </Location>
...
```

And here is /3dkit/kit.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/3dkit')
print 'user =', os.environ['USER']

from kit import app as application
```

The print command fails with the exception

```
KeyError: 'USER'
```

Yet this command in the terminal window:

```
sudo -u 3dkit printenv USER
```

outputs "3dkit" as expected.

It's not just this environment variable. No matter how I try to set an environment variable, whether in /home/3dkit/.profile, or in /etc/environment, or any other way I can think of, it is ignored in my WSGI file. The only way I can make it work is to explicitly call os.environ and set an environment variable in the WSGI file itself.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How did you set the environment variable? Did you `export` it so it is available outside the shell?

Comment: In the case of /home/3dkit/.profile, yes, I used export. In the case of /etc/environment, no, as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables.

Answer (score 3):

The WSGI daemon process runs in a very santizied environment, and the only variables set are PATH and LANG.  (And in my case, NOTIFY_SOCKET, since Apache is started by systemd).  USER, SHELL, and all the other variables you see in an interactive shell are not set, and the shell initialization files (.profile, etc) aren't run.

Are you using `USER` as an example, or do you actually want to identify the owner of the process?  `os.getuid()` and friends will return the uid, and you can convert it into the username with something like `pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]` (see the `pwd` and `os` modules).

If what you actually want is to access typical server environment variables one might see in a CGI script (e.g. HTTP_REFERER, REMOTE_ADDR, etc), those are in the server environment, which in Flask is accessible via Werkzeug's Request object, which is available with, e.g. `from flask import Flask, request`.  You can then access, e.g. `request.environ['HTTP_REFERER']`